# C# + add local attachment to Gapps calendar using Google.Apis.Calendar.v3;

Tags: google-calendar-api

Attachment adding from drive to calendars is possible. I want to add attachment to calendar from my machine local path. how can I add??

Comment: Welcome to stack please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.  Please show us what you have tried and any errors you may have encountered.  We are not here to do it for you.

Comment: You will first need to upload that file to drive.